# Accessing .NET 4.0 method from a C# .NET 3.5 assembly (App targetting 4.0 Framework (CLR))

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a utility assembly, "Reg.dll", which is built using .NET 3.5 target framework.

Reg.dll is used by some applications with target 3.5 target framework, and other newer apps that target 4.0 (upgrading the 3.5 applications is not currently an option, due to release constraints, but will happen eventually.)  I'm assuming this means that the code in Reg.dll will be running in either a 4.0 or 3.5 CLR context at runtime, depending on the app target framework.

I now have a situation where I would like to have the Reg.dll detect if it is running in either the 4.0 or 3.5 CLR (which I can assume if not 4.0), and execute a 4.0-only method (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.FromHandle) if it is running inside the 4.0 CLR.

A co-worker has recommended building two assemblies, one targetting 3.5, and the other 4.0, and dynamically loading the appropriate one at runtime.  This sounds like it would work, however I suspect that this can also be accomplished using something like the System.Reflection features to detect for the existing of this specific method, and then somehow dynamically invoking it.

Is this possible, or am I better off going with the multiple assembly route?  Code fragments/references that I would use as a model would also be helpful, as I haven't worked much with this aspect of .NET before.

Comment: using System.Reflection feature sounds better option, with less deployment hassles.

Comment: you won't be able to load the 4.0 assembly at runtime on a 2.0 CLR, you will get an exception.

Comment: @Furgan - that's my thinking, and my preferred route if it is possible.  Have you done this?  Looking for any helpful references beyond MSDN for implementation.

Comment: @Daniel - I am never attempting to load a 4.0 assembly on a 2.0 CLR in this scenario.

Comment: Are you sure the 3.5 assembly running in 4.0 context doesn't call 4.0 methods by default? I can't check at the moment but I remember having kind of a similar problem previously and I would get `MissingMethodException`.

Comment: @paulius_l: 3.5 assemblies run fine on the 4 CLR, the runtime redirects any methods that have moved between the two versions.